# How to present $B_{ijz}$ intersections of N sets by Matrix?

Tags: matrices, inclusion-exclusion

You can get all sets of Venn's diagrams intersections and unions by Richard Stanley's Exclusion-Inclusion principle [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). 
I am thinking how you can present them all by a matrix.

I can only make a matrix for two set intersections $B_{ij}$ and the individual parts $B_{ii}$ like this

\begin{equation}
B_{s} =  
\begin{bmatrix}
    B_{11}       & B_{12} & B_{13} & \dots & B_{1n} & B_{1(n+1)} \\
    0            & B_{22} & B_{23} & \dots & B_{2n} & B_{2(n+1)} \\
    ... \\
    0            & 0      & 0      & \dots & B_{dn} & B_{d(n+1)} \\
    0            & 0      & 0      & \dots & 0      & B_{(d+1)(n+1)}
\end{bmatrix}.
\label{eq:generalAssociations}
\end{equation}

Take for instance #123 intersection of all there sets, ABC in Fig. 1. 
How can you formulate a matrix to include such intersections too?

Fig. 1 Example of ABC intersection of three sets A,B,C

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Could you make an example?

Comment: What is the corresponding matrix to your Venn diagram?

Comment: @user251257 I do not have one because I cannot make one. I can only make a matrix for two sets.

Comment: then please post an example with two sets. At least I have absolutely no idea what you mean.

Comment: @user251257 I extend the case here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2028047/17474 for my general case